# deleted document in pouchDB not deleted

Tags: pouchdb

First i'm making an offline storage for a chrome extension with pouchDB, later i will add syncronization.

It seems that db.remove(doc) doesn't actually remove the doc from database, because when i update my UI after deletion, allDocs shows the deleted document as well.

After searching for a couple of hours I can't find any info about this matter on the web. I did find one mention somewhere:

"...actually just adds _deleted:true which in Couch means that next time the database is compacted previous version can be removed, note you can’t remove it entirely because if you did you wouldn’t be able to tell other databases so when you replicated. "

OK but how can i now get allDocs except those who are ready for deletion later on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two potential issues here:

1. Replication of deleted docs had a bug in 3.0.0 and 3.0.1. It's fixed in 3.0.2.
2. `allDocs` does return the deleted docs, but only if you use `keys` to specify the IDs. Otherwise it only gives the undeleted docs.

Comment: The problem in the end was that i use jquery to build my dinamic content for the popup, and i store for each <li> a data-doc object containing required document info for deleting them afterwards. So later on some .on("click") function i retrieve the pouchDB object for deletion. The problem was actually stupid, i had some bad unescaping while building the content. However, it seems that with plain javascript you can attach listener on each created element, so it's possible passing the object around, withoud the need for data-.

Comment: I'm still seeing the exact same issue above with 3.1.0. Looks like the deleted replication doesn't happen quick enough between the delete commands and the query that happens later...

Comment: We'll release 3.2.0 soon; it should be fixed there. There was an issue with replication of deleted documents.